# Multiple tinyint when insert data into MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code which insert questions and answers for a quiz into a mysql database and for each answer a specifically tinyint number. With this method I can choose which one is the correct answer by allocating the number 1 to it and 0 to the rest of them. What I want is to can allocate to the wrong answers the numbers 2, 3 and 4, not 0 to all. I hope you understood. My English is not so good. Thank you very much !

My code:

```
    // Question query
    $query = "INSERT INTO `questions`(question_number, text)
                VALUES('$question_number', '$question_text')";

    // Run query
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    // Validate insert
    if ($insert_row) {
        foreach ($choices as $choice => $choice_text) {
            if($choice_text != '') {
                if($correct_choice == $choice) {
                    $is_correct = 1;
                } else{
                    $is_correct = 0;
                }
```

Comment: what criteria is necessary for a wrong answer to be allocated 2 or 3 or 4?

Comment: and why are you inserting into your database before validating?

Comment: The whole code is bigger and I post only the relevant part of it. What I want is not to allocate 0 to all, but 2 for answer 2 (for example), 3 for answer 3 and 4 for the fourth one, Thank you !

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thank you @tadman !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you specify the wrong answer when it's not correct?

```
if($choice_text != '') {
        if($correct_choice == $choice) {
            $is_correct = 1;
        } else{
            $is_correct = $choice;
        }
```